# Microsoft ODBC for Oracle is missing

Tags: sql-server, excel, oracle, vba

I'm trying to connect Oracle database from Excel VBA, but got some run time error and figured out that 'Microsoft ODBC for Oracle' is missing in 'ODBC Data Source Administrator' under 'Drivers' tab.

Under 'Drivers' tab I could see only 'SQL Server' - so do I need to install 'Microsoft ODBC for Oracle' manually? Because I thought that 'Microsoft ODBC for Oracle' should have got installed by default with OS. Is my assumption wrong here? If so please confirm and also let me know which application would install that driver by default.... because I have never faced this issue in most of the client machines..... so bit confused here.... please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need to install, if it isn't already present.  Microsoft don't recommend using their ODBC Driver for Oracle, anymore.

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Windows. Avoid
>   using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify
>   applications that currently use this feature. Instead, use the ODBC
>   driver provided by Oracle.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713590(v=vs.85).aspx).

Instead use the [Oracle driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-098976.html).

Answer (score 1):

Which 'ODBC Data Source Administrator' do you use? 32-bit or 64-bit? If your Excel is 32-bit (which is most likely the case) you also have to use 32-bit ODBC Data Sources.

Start `%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` to launch the 32-bit version.

Note, ODBC driver for Oracle from Microsoft supports only 32-bit, 64-bit is not available. As already mentioned it is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and should not be used for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

See Whether it is coming or not under the add section
Probably you did not set connection with you database that's why you are getting run time error

[image: Step1]

[image: Step 2]

Answer (score 0):

I created the Microsoft ODBC drivers for Oracle this way,

1. Find the table in MS Access not in Oracle (make sure all the column names and table names are Upper Case)
2. Right click > Export > ODBC Databases
3. Click OK
4. Click on the "Machine Data Source" tab
5. Click the New button
6. Click the radio button "User Data Sources"
7. Click the "Next >" button
8. Scroll down until you see the "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" driver
9. Select it and click the "Next >" button
10. Add all the credentials and this will create driver and add it your Data Sources going forward